# Writing HTML to new window opened issue

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
 <div class="col3">
    <a id = "training-launch-button" href="javascript:void(0);" title=" My title here"  class="button" onClick="Test();">Launch</a>
 </div>     

  function Test() {
      var new_window= window.open('','Ratting','width=550,height=170,0,status=0,resizable=1');
      new_window.document.createElement("div");
      document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = '<ol><li>html data</li></ol>';     

  }
```

something is not right, I dont see the ordered list item?
I eventually want to build some HTML in the new window.

Comment: look at the source of the created page

Comment: getElementsByTagName returns an array with multiple elements, ocument.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML might work better. Or just use id's and getElementById.

Comment: open it in chrome and right-click->inspectElement, check for errors and paste the relevant error here please

Comment: Try using `createElement()` to create the new **div** instead of `createAttribute()`!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Js

```
function Test() {
   var newWindow= window.open('','Ratting','width=550,height=170,0,status=0,resizable=1');
   var newContent = "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>One Sub Window</TITLE></HEAD>";
   newContent += "<BODY><div><ol><li>html data</li></ol></div>";
   newContent += "</BODY></HTML>";
   newWindow.document.write(newContent);
   newWindow.document.close();  
 }
```

Comment: Why do you use `createAttribute("div")` to create the `div` instead of `createElement()`?

Comment: thanks all I changed the new_window.document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML  and new_window.document.createElement("div"); but still nothing, I right click and view source and all I have is <HTML></HTML>?

Comment: I updated my code completely and checked it. Its perfectly working.

Answer (score 0):

I would try

`new_window.document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = ...`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem; getElementsByName returns an array, not one element, so;

```
new_window.document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = '<ol><li>html data</li></ol>';
```

NB: I have a '[0]' in there

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
var new_window= window.open('','Ratting','width=550,height=170,0,status=0,resizable=1');
var div = new_window.document.createElement('div');
new_window.document.body.appendChild(div);
div.innerHTML = '<ol><li>html data</li></ol>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually not appending the new div to the new document's body, you'll have to use `.appendChild()` method for that, see this :

```
function Test() {
    var new_window = window.open('','Ratting','width=550,height=170,0,status=0,resizable=1');
    var div = new_window.document.createElement("div");
    new_window.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
    div.innerHTML = '<ol><li>html data</li></ol>';         
}
```

[see here - working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jQDs8/)